# rendering an httpresponse object as html

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want an html sequence to be rendered in HTML, rather it is getting displayed as a string.

Views.py -

```
from django.utils.html import escape
ret_html = """<p> Please click the following link 
to authorize the application - <a href='""" + auth_url + """' target='_blank'>Authorize!</a> </p>"""
            return HttpResponse(escape(ret_html))
```

The above gets rendered exactly like this in the browser -

```
<p> Please click the following link to authorize the application - <a href='/social/addtwitter/' target='_blank'>Authorize!</a> </p>
```

Whereas I would want it to look something like this -

Please click the following link to authorize the application - [Authorize!][1]

Any idea, I could do some tweaks to render the string as html.

PS : I am aware of `render` and `render_to_response`

Comment: You need to mark it as safe: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`|safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) in the template

Or just

```
return HttpResponse(safe(escape(ret_html)))
```

It is recommended to use `render` or `render_to_response`